# Magento - Get Country Id from Name - is there a easier/quicker way?

Tags: magento

I need to load the 2 letter ISO2 country ID for a given country name.

Right now, I use the following method to do this:

```
// Method to Get countryId from CountryName
function getCountryId($countryName) {
    $countryId = '';
    $countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection();
    foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
        if ($countryName == $country->getName()) {
            $countryId = $country->getCountryId();
            break;
        }
    }
    $countryCollection = null;
    return $countryId;
}
```

Usage:

```
var_dump(getCountryId('Germany'));
```

Outputs:

```
string(2) "DE"
```

Is there a easier/quicker way to do this instead of loading the country collection and iterating through it every time?

Comment: Unfortunately the directory/country model only ofers a loadByCode method, and not a loadByName. You could implement such a method yourself, but since you already have a working solution, it could be just overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, looping is the only way you'll achieve this.

The country names are stored in XML files in `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/` and they're organized by locale (en, es, fr) and then country code, not country name.

Since it's not a SQL table you can't add a `WHERE` clause (using Magento's `addFieldToFilter()`), so you'll be looping through the XML nodes anyway.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I get the following error:

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'' in /home/www-data/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Comment: You're right.  This collection is stored differently from any I've seen before.  You have to loop

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way, because of translations. This is function for getting country name, you can't reverse it

```
public function getName()
{
    if(!$this->getData('name')) {
        $this->setData(
            'name',
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($this->getId())
        );
    }
    return $this->getData('name');
}
```