# Header Shipping Rate Country Flag

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento, header

I would like shipping rate flag appears on web site header,when customers access my site their country.How can I edit header page just like this on magento ?I have searched magento extension but not found anything.
Here is caps what I am like;
[image]

When I add this code in header.phtml bottom of topbar code,I see this result;
First this code;

```html
<div class="col-md6 col-sm-6 col-sms12">
                    <div class="currency-language">
                       echo $this->__('Shipping to'). ': ';
                       if ($this->getCountryCode()) {
    echo '<img src="' . $this->getSkinUrl('images/countries/' . strtolower($this->getCountryCode()) . '.png') .'" alt="' . $this->getCountryName() . '" /> ';
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_top') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
                        
                    </div>
```

and here is the result caps;
[image]

Also can I edited this code for GEO IP ?

Comment: Could you show us your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

System / Configuration / Design / {header tab} / Welcome Text

Add your text here. Unfortunately you can't add any images here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Upload all the country flags in one folder with the country code names like: it.png for Italy (let's say you have them saved here: public_html\skin\frontend\ .. \images\countries). You can download a standard set from [here](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/).

Then use something like this code to retrieve them:

```
echo $this->__('Shipping to'). ': ';
if ($this->getCountryCode()) {
    echo '<img src="' . $this->getSkinUrl('images/countries/' . strtolower($this->getCountryCode()) . '.png') .'" alt="' . $this->getCountryName() . '" /> ';
```

Comment: Sorry for late respond,I edited my first comment could you check for me please?

Comment: @KaanBurak dude you can't use getCountryCode() in that way unless you have already defined it in your app (it's not a magic function). I was just trying to give you an idea on how to implement the flags in your question. There are different ways to get the country code in magento. For example look at this answer: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/21438867/2568469  ... 
Furthermore you should always embed your PHP code inside <?php ?> tag.