# Setting country for all customers in Magento

Tags: sql, magento

I just went through hours of meticulous work to transfer over 20k customers for an access db into Magento 1.7.

Now the issue i am having is the country is not being recognized or picked up by magento for all the address. I do not want to go through another import/export process.

I just need a simple SQL script to set all the COUNTRY fields (in all address related tables) to "US" or "United States" (whichever format Magento uses)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add this line Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); in the @liyakat's Answer just before the $app = Mage::app('default'); code and then execute this script again

Comment: tried, still the same.  The country fields have to change from "United States" to "US"  and its not happening...

Comment: Ok, so i found a simple way to do this.  Just did a Find/Replace from myPHPadmin in the table called "mage_customer_address_entity_varchar" 

(My installation has mage_ prefix for tables.)

Anyways that did the trick pretty easily and quickly.  Thank you everyone for your input!

Answer (score 1):

you can use below script to set US as default country on all customer

**EDIT**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('default');


$customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

foreach ($customers as $customer) {

    // customer object
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
    $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

    if ($default_shipping_id = $customer->getDefaultShipping()) {
         $address->load($default_shipping_id);
    } else {
         $address
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
         ;
         $address_arr = $address->getData();

         // country
         if ( !isset($address_arr['country_id']) ) {

               $address->setCountryId('US');

            try {
                $address->save();

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                error_log(json_encode($e->getMessage()));
            }

         }

    }

}
```

hope this will sure help to you

Just let me know if i could help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help.  Where do u run this script?  I assume it has to be in a php file where database connection is already established?  I know it may be a stupid question but my brain is fried right now!

Comment: you can use my update code to set country in your customer address, just run this script beside `app` folder or load mage.php any where to run this. pls dont forget to accpet my answer if this could solve ur isssue

Comment: I ran this in a php file from the root folder, it executed without any errors (returned with a blank page after several seconds, but i am still having the same issue. is there a way to do this directly from SQL? and will this change ALL the addresses in the address book of all customers?

Comment: I also found that the country from the imported customers says "United States" in the table field  so i am assuming it will have to REPLACE the country-id field, (if it already exists) with the proper markup for "US".

Comment: yes you are right this value is store in `customer_address_entity_varchar` you can directly update

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to the OP. In my CSV import for customers I had the country name, not the 2 letter ISO code. The import did not complain. However when a customer tried to place an order not shipping method could be computed - this turned out to be because the country code was wrong.

I took the script @liyakat wrote in his excellent answer and I have made a number of enhancements that I would like to share:

- It will fix the Shipping AND Billing address
- If there is a value in the countryId it will do a lookup to find the code from that country name... but...
- If the countryId already contains a two letter code it
  leaves it alone
- It defaults to GB "United Kingdom" cause I am a
  British
- It sets the time_limit to zero - no limit, I don't know if
  this affects command line PHP or not, but I wasn't going to risk it
  stopping half way.
- It prints the email of the customer it is
  processing. It is quite slow, so this gives you an idea of the
  progress.

The getCountryId() code comes from this [question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786233/magento-get-country-id-from-name-is-there-a-easier-quicker-way)

```
    ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    require 'app/Mage.php';
    $app = Mage::app('default'); 

    // Method to Get countryId from CountryName
    function getCountryId($countryName) {

    //Most will be here, so save a lookup...
    if ($countryName == "United Kingdom")
    {
        $countryId = "GB";
    }
    else
    {
        $countryId = '';
        $countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection();
        foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
        if ($countryName == $country->getName()) {
            $countryId = $country->getCountryId();
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    $countryCollection = null;
    return $countryId;
    }

    function fixAddress($customer, $address, $isBilling)
    {
        if ($isBilling)
        {
            $address
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1') ;           
        }
        else {
            $address
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
        }


        $address_arr = $address->getData();
        $save = false;

        if ( isset($address_arr['country_id']) ) {

            if (strlen($address_arr['country_id']) != 2) {
                $isoCountry = getCountryId($address_arr['country_id']); 
                $address->setCountryId($isoCountry);
                $save = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $address->setCountryId('GB');
            $save = true;
        }


        if ($save) {
            try {
                $address->save();

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                error_log(json_encode($e->getMessage()));
            }
    }


    }



    $customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {

        // customer object
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $default_billing_id = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
    $address->load($default_billing_id);

        echo $customer->getEmail() . ' ' . getCountryId($address->getCountryId()) . "
\n";


        fixAddress($customer, $address, true);

        if ($default_shipping_id = $customer->getDefaultShipping()) {
             $address->load($default_shipping_id);
             fixAddress($customer, $address, true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Works beautifully for me. I couldn't get it to work in the browser, but it runs like a well oiled machine in command line. Thanks for this!